# What is the easiest way to spin up a node/js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having trouble building a node/js app with various frameworks. I keep getting the error `require is not defined` even though I have followed various browserify tutorials to fix it.

To give a flavour of what I want to do. I want the app to be able to be ran on a server and then I can npm install **anything** and these things work smoothly. I have been using express, firebase etc to handle some of my issues.

This is an extract of my `app.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var firebase = require('firebase');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/html/index.html');
});

app.get('/welcome', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/html/welcome.html');
});
```

I have tried to use `bundle.js` to get require working but it still insists it is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Browserify will let you transpile some code so it will run in the browser.

It won't let you do things which are fundamentally impossible in the browser (such as running an HTTP server as you are trying to do here).

If you want to run code that requires Node JS then you need to run it through Node JS. Typically via `node app.js` in your command line shell.